# fine-tune BERT for semantic textual similarity

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I’m trying to use BERT (or any language embedding models) to solve a semantic text similarity problem: given a product A, find product B, which is basically the same underlying product, with a few key differences. For example, “ABC green T-shirt” matches with “ABC green T-shirt (2-count)”; however, “ABC green T-shirt” does NOT match with “ABC red T-shirt (2-count)”. So my goal is to refine BERT to pay more attention to, in this particular case, color, while not losing sight of the more important information, T-shirt.

What I’m doing now is follow Natural Language Inference — Sentence-Transformers documentation

train BERT with correct pairs, such as “ABC green T-shirt” matches with “ABC green T-shirt (2-count)”. There are about 150k training instances.

train 1) model with triplets, such as (“ABC green T-shirt” , “ABC green T-shirt (2-count)”, “ABC red T-shirt (2-count)”. There are about 5k training instances, so overfitting can be a problem here.

After these steps, I saw a slight improvements on matching accuracy. So my question is:

am I on the right direction?

what’re the more up-to-date fine-tuning methods compared to the ones in sentence transformer documentation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for learning text similarity, which utilizes Sentence Transformers style fine-tuning, is well-aligned with the latest trends in natural language processing. However, here are some insights:

- **Data Augmentation:** To mitigate the risk of overfitting in your
  triplet dataset, consider augmenting your data. This can be done by
  creating new training examples or by making minor modifications to
  existing ones, such as altering certain attributes while maintaining
  the product type.
- **Hard Negative Mining:**  In your triplet training, ensure that the non-matching items (the third item in the triplet) are *hard negatives* –– these are items that are very similar but not quite matches. This makes the training more challenging and effective.

Keep in mind that finding the most suitable fine-tuning methods for semantic matching is task-dependent, and there isn't a one-size-fits-all solution in the field.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm also wondering if I should train the model sequentially - first correct pairs, then triplets on top of it?

Comment: Yes, I believe that training your model sequentially—first on correct pairs and then on triplets—is a strategic planning here. This approach could potentially enhance the model's capability to avoid overfitting during the second task (on triplet dataset), particularly considering the smaller size of your dataset for that phase.